# ajustar textarea al tamaño del texto

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Estoy trabajando con textareas y me gustaría que se ajustase el height del textarea a la altura del texto. Ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo este elemento pero al empezar a escribir dentro de el le aparece un pequeño padding-bottom.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy buscando que no le añada ese padding y se ajustase a la ultima linea del texto, he probado con varias propiedades css y no lo he conseguido. No se si es posible y si lo es como seria.
Gracias.

Comment: Puedes mostrar lo que has intentado usando un [mcve] y siguiendo [ask] ? Asi nos contextualizas en tu problema y codigo y podemos ayudarte a arreglarlo. Un saludo

Comment: A ver creo que es debido a que la aplicación usa el framework jquery mobile. Pero se supone que con un padding:0; deberia de sobreescribir el estilo y no añadir ese pequeño padding

Comment: Creo el elemento <textarea id=""></textarea> y or defecto lo crea con ese pequeño padding

Comment: le aparece el padding-bottom cuando empiezo a introducir caracteres. Alguna idea de porque es debido?

Answer (score 6):

Al no ver el código, no sé por qué se te genera ese padding-bottom, no obstante a ver si este código te puede ayudar a que cumpla el cometido que pretendes:

```js
var textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');

textarea.addEventListener('keydown', autosize);
             
function autosize(){
  var el = this;
  setTimeout(function(){
    el.style.cssText = 'height:auto; padding:0';
    el.style.cssText = 'height:' + el.scrollHeight + 'px';
  },0);
}
```

```css
textarea{  
  overflow:hidden;
  margin:50px auto;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<textarea rows='1' placeholder='Textarea'></textarea>
```

Un saludo!

Comment: Muchas gracias, voy a echarle un vistazo al codigo porque debe de haber algo que no deja actuar a esto correctamente. Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Genial. Si sigues teniendo problemas con tu código, compártelo y seguro que le damos solución. Un saludo.

Comment: Excelente, me sirvió mucho, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Quizá esta solución te puede interesar.

Es una de las propuestas compartidas en [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/vsync/pen/frudD)

```js
// Applied globally on all textareas with the "autoExpand" class
$(document)
    .one('focus.autoExpand', 'textarea.autoExpand', function(){
        var savedValue = this.value;
        this.value = '';
        this.baseScrollHeight = this.scrollHeight;
        this.value = savedValue;
    })
    .on('input.autoExpand', 'textarea.autoExpand', function(){
        var minRows = this.getAttribute('data-min-rows')|0, rows;
        this.rows = minRows;
        rows = Math.ceil((this.scrollHeight - this.baseScrollHeight) / 17);
        this.rows = minRows + rows;
    });
```

```css
html,body{ height:100%; }
body{ background:#4A90E2; display:flex; align-items:center; }

textarea{  
  display:block;
  box-sizing: padding-box;
  overflow:hidden;

  padding:10px;
  width:250px;
  font-size:14px;
  margin:50px auto;
  border-radius:6px;
  box-shadow:2px 2px 8px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  border:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class='autoExpand' rows='3' data-min-rows='3' placeholder='Auto-Expanding Textarea'></textarea>
```

---

O bien esta otra, usando Bootstrap.

Puedes modificar los márgenes en el CSS.

[Ver fuente](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37630464/5587982).

```js
function autoTextarea(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).addEventListener('keyup', function() {
    this.style.overflow = 'hidden';
    this.style.height = 0;
    this.style.height = this.scrollHeight + 'px';
  }, false);
}

autoTextarea('txtarea');
```

```css
body {
  padding: 50px;
}

textarea {
  /* margin:0px 0px; this is redundant anyways since its specified below*/
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  /* increased! */
  /* height:16px; */
  /* line-height:16px; */
  width: 100%;
  /* changed from 96 to 100% */
  display: block;
  /* margin:0px auto; not needed since i have width 100% now */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">

<textarea id="txtarea" placeholder="Escribe..."></textarea>
```